# Can I show millisecond for file modified time in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-vista, windows-explorer, windows-server-2008

I am wondering if I can get file modification time in milliseconds when using Windows explorer or 3rd party tools?

Comment: There is a similar question with more helpful answers here : https://superuser.com/questions/937380/get-creation-time-of-file-in-milliseconds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.lochan.org/2005/keith-cl/useful/win32time.html) (under Timing on Windows), no, because the OS timer tick is only 64 times per second (Windows XP). However, to keep accurate timing for other instructions besides file timestamps, you could use QueryPerformanceCounter, referenced [here](http://www.lochan.org/2005/keith-cl/useful/win32time.html) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/e5f9dac1-2023-4ea4-9bab-89b6149e5528/).