# Get creation time of file in milliseconds

Tags: windows, file-management

Is there a way to get the creation time of a file in windows in a higher accuracy? I want to get the creation time of an mp4-video in milliseconds. Is this possible?

Comment: I have to ask why you need this accuracy?

Comment: I record some sensor data on an Android device together with a video. I wrote the sensor logging by myself and log the system time together with each sensor value. For recording the video I use the standard camera activity.
After sending the data to a PC I want to analyse it. For merging the video with the sensor data I have to know when the video started. Seconds are a little bit too coarse so I'm looking for a way to get a more exact starting time of the video.

Comment: Note: if you need that kind of relationship between two data streams, it is usually essential to put a registration signal in the stream (like the old clapboards used in movies as the director calls "action".  The clap was a visual cue and audio cue, allowing the two or more streams to be synced later).   In some situations, the time delay between creating the file in kernel mode (and recording the timestamp) and waking up your process to let it know it has a file handle to use could actually be higher than the tolerances you have for your data.

Comment: When you copy your stuff from Android to somewhere else, make sure all the copy tools preserve timestamp precision.  Note that many copy tools will make the `ctime` of the copy be the time it was copied.

Comment: On windows, I'd use cygwin/mingw `stat` to get all 3 timestamps.  Of course, that's because I normally use GNU/Linux.

Comment: @Cort Ammon I used this kind of registration signal before but I want to automate the analysing. That is why I am looking for an alternative way. I will figure out if it is accurate enough for my purpose.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't think of that, it seems a little more accurate than the `wmic` solution. Do you mind if I add it to my answer?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Go right ahead.  Collecting useful stuff from comments into answers makes the site better.

Comment: @Moab Sure, since you asked, I am interested in this level of accuracy because I want to get a general idea of the order that some file system events happened, from the OS's perspective.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Timestamp resolution

The creation timestamp of a file in windows depends on the file system:

- FAT/VFAT has a maximum resolution of 2s
- NTFS has a maximum resolution of 100 ns

---

#### wmic solution

You can use `wmic` to retrieve the file creation date to the nearest microsecond.

Example:

```
F:\test>wmic datafile where name="f:\\test\\test.txt" get creationdate | findstr /brc:[0-9]
20150329221650.080654+060
```

The creationdate `20150329221650.080654+060` is a timestamp, with the following format:

```
yyyymmddHHMMSS.xxxxxxsUUU
```

where:

- `yyyy` Four-digit year (0000 through 9999).
- `mm` Two-digit month (01 through 12).
- `dd` Two-digit day of the month (01 through 31).
- `HH` Two-digit hour of the day using the 24-hour clock (00 through 23).
- `MM` Two-digit minute in the hour (00 through 59).
- `SS` Two-digit number of seconds in the minute (00 through 59).
- `xxxxxx` Six-digit number of microseconds in the second (000000 through 999999)
- `s` Plus sign (`+`) or minus sign (`-`) to indicate a positive or negative offset from Coordinated Universal Times (UTC).
- `UUU` Three-digit offset indicating the number of minutes that the originating time zone deviates from UTC.

---

#### stat solution

You can also use `stat` (from a [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) or [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) installation).

Example:

```
DavidPostill@Hal /f/test
$ stat test.txt | grep Birth
 Birth: 2015-03-29 22:16:50.080654200 +0100
```

---

#### dir output for comparison

```
F:\test>dir /t:c test.txt
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

29/03/2015  22:16                32 test.txt
               1 File(s)             32 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,798,546,849,792 bytes free
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html)
- [Working with Dates and Times using WMI](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198928.aspx)
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) is an excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: Also "`xxxxxx` represents the milliseconds" is misleading as in the example you give, it appears to represent microseconds (I'm not sure what happened to the tenths of microseconds that NTFS supposedly offers).

Comment: A note of caution: just because a timestamps contains a high frequency digit, such as the 100 nanoseconds' digit, does not mean the clock can be used as a reliable time source at the 100ns range.  It merely states that there's a lot of bits of content which is [hopefully] monotonic and roughly correlates to "real" time.

Comment: Thanks for great answer! Your "maximum precision allowed by the file system." is misleading. The System allows one more digit, that is not available via wmi.

Comment: @MarisB. Do you have a link/reference for this claim?

Comment: On FAT, the granularity of creation timestamps is 0.1 s but the granularity of modification timestamps is 2.0 s. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/file-times

Comment: The `wmic` command can be used for a directory by replacing `datafile` with `fsdir`.

Comment: Doesn't FAT have a maximum resolution of 10ms?  According to [here](https://academy.cba.mit.edu/classes/networking_communications/SD/FAT.pdf#page=23), the FAT field for the second of the creation of the file has 2-seconds granularity, _but_ it has a hundredth/tenth seconds field, too

Answer (score 1):

A clever way is demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180592/showing-ntfs-timestamp-with-100-nsec-granularity

It's using VBScript to query WMI's CIM database and return the `FILETIME` structure associated to a file.

There are also open source tools that can inspect a media file's metadata, such as [EXIFtool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) which is geared towards managing the metadata of media created by digital cameras.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way how to obtain this in Matlab:

You can use the [GetFileTime](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24671-filetime/content//GetFileTime.m) function  written by Jan Simon. If you don't want to compile your own mex files, you can also download the compiled files [here](http://www.n-simon.de/mex/).

It is not as exact as using wmic (only ms) but for my purpose it is suitable.

Answer (score -2):

It [depends on the file system](http://jpsoft.com/help/timestamps.htm): FAT has 2 second resolution, NTFS *theoretically* has 100 ns resolution, but the actual [resolution is 10 ms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That said, interrupts have higher priority than disk I/O, and I'm not sure the effect write-caching has on the time stamp. [Multimedia timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are optimized for accuracy, so would be the preferred way to implement timing.

You can use an existing tool such as [XYplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/release_12.50.php) to view high-resolution timestamps, or [image: XYplorer showing ms], you may prefer to write your own application. Use the [File.GetCreationTime Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); it returns a [DateTime Structure with Millisecond](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

Comment: um... not to be rude, but, did you read @DavidPostill's answer?

Comment: "NTFS theoretically has 100 ns resolution, but the actual [resolution is 10 ms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" is **incorrect** - that link actually says "**on NT FAT**, create time has a resolution of 10 milliseconds". That does **not** mean **NTFS** has that resolution. You can see from my answer that on NTFS `wmic` shows a resolution to the nearest **microsecond**.

Comment: There is a difference between theoretical and maximum resolution, one indicates well the maximum resolution, the other indicates, more of an averag resolution.

Comment: @DavidPostill If the clock only increments the time every 10ms, then having a datetime filed that can represent 100ns still has an accuracy of only 10ms. The typical UtcNow APIs (as opposed to high performance counters which are designed for measuring time *differences*) increment the time every 0.5-16ms on windows, so this answer is quite plausible.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Yes, but - "The best resource for retrieving the system time is the GetSystemTimeAsFileTime API. It is a fast access API that is able to hold sufficiently accurate (100 ns units) values in its arguments." - I don't have access to the Windows source code so I don't know what calls are used under the hood when manipulating file timestamps. We don't know what the **actual** resolution is - that's just guessing.